# How to send the member's avatar in a RichEmbed

Tags: typescript, bots, discord.js

I'm trying to make a welcome embed with the member's avatar as the image of the RichEmbed.

This is my code:

```
client.on("guildMemberAdd", member => {

let welcomeEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed ()
        .setAuthor(`${member.nickname} has joined the server!`)
        .setImage(member.displayAvatarURL)
        .setFooter(member.joinedAt)
        .setColor([0, 255 ,0])
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Member doesn`t have property displayAvatarURL, you need get [user](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User).

And you will got `undefined` at `member.nickname`, if user has no nickname on your server, so better use `.displayName` its will return a `user.username` if user has no nickname.

```
client.on("guildMemberAdd", member => {

let welcomeEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed ()
        .setAuthor(`${member.displayName} has joined the server!`)
        .setImage(member.user.displayAvatarURL)
        .setFooter(member.joinedAt)
        .setColor([0, 255 ,0])
})
```